# When doing classification, why do I get different precision for the same testing data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision

I am testing a dataset with two labels 'A' and 'B' on a decision tree classifier. I accidentally found out that the model get different precision result on the same testing data. I want to know why.

Here is what I do, I train the model, and test it on

```
1. the testing set, 
2. the data only labelled 'A' in the testing set, 
3. and the data only labelled 'B'.
```

Here is what I got:

1. for testing dataset

   ```
        precision    recall  f1-score   support
   A       0.94      0.95      0.95     25258
   B       0.27      0.22      0.24      1963
   ```
2. for data only labelled 'A' in testing dataset

   ```
       precision    recall  f1-score   support

   A       1.00      0.95      0.98     25258
   B       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
   ```
3. for data only labelled 'B' in testing dataset

   ```
       precision    recall  f1-score   support

   A       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
   B       1.00      0.22      0.36      1963
   ```

The training dataset and model are the same, the data in 2 and 3rd test are also same with those in 1. Why the precision for 'A' and 'B' differ so much? What is the real precision for this model? Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly is strange here? If there are not any `B`'s in your test set but you still predict them (case #2), the precision for `B` will indeed be zero - and similarly for `A`'s in case #3. By definition, precision & recall are calculated *per class*, and not per model.

Comment: What puzzles me here is not the zero precision, but the 100% precision of A in case #2 and B in case #3. Is that true that the model is able to predict all the A in case #2 and B in case #3 correctly? If it is true, then why it cannot predict A and B correctly in case #1? In other word, why the precision is not 1 in case #1 (for both A and B)? The data are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound confused, and it is not at all clear **why** you are interested in metrics where you have completely remove one of the two labels from your evaluation set.

Let's explore the issue with some reproducible dummy data:

```python
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
y_true = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
y_pred = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
target_names = ['A', 'B']

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

Result:

```python
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       0.50      0.50      0.50         4
          B       0.33      0.33      0.33         3

avg / total       0.43      0.43      0.43         7
```

Now, let's keep only class A in our `y_true`:

```python
indA = np.where(y_true==0)
print(indA)
print(y_true[indA])
print(y_pred[indA])
```

Result:

```python
(array([0, 2, 5, 6], dtype=int64),)
[0 0 0 0] 
[0 1 0 1]
```

Now, here is the definition of precision from the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html):

> The precision is the ratio `tp / (tp + fp)` where `tp` is the number of true positives and `fp` the number of false positives. The precision is intuitively the ability of the classifier not to label as positive a sample that is negative.

For class A, a true positive (`tp`) would be a case where the true class is A (`0` in our case), and we have indeed predict A (`0`); from above, it is apparent that `tp=2`.

The tricky part is the false positives (`fp`): they are the cases where we have predicted A (`0`), where the true label is B (`1`). But it is apparent here that we **cannot** have any such cases, since we have (intentionally) removed all the B's from our `y_true` (why we would want to do such a thing? I don't know, it does not make any sense at all); hence, `fp=0` in this (weird) setting. Hence, our precision for class A will be `tp / (tp+0) = tp/tp = 1`.

Which is the exact same result given by the classification report:

```python
print(classification_report(y_true[indA], y_pred[indA], target_names=target_names))
# result:

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       1.00      0.50      0.67         4
          B       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

avg / total       1.00      0.50      0.67         4
```

and obviously the case for B is identical.

> why the precision is not 1 in case #1 (for both A and B)? The data are the same

No, they are very obviously **not** the same - the *ground truth* is altered!

Bottom line: removing classes from your `y_true` before computing precision etc. **does not make any sense** at all (i.e. your reported results in case #2 and case #3 are of no practical use whatsoever); but, since for whatever reasons you decide to do so, your reported results are exactly as expected.